# Unable to record mouse curser in VirtualBox when recording screen

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, virtualbox, mouse

I want to record the screen inside VirtualBox. For that it would be quite handy if I could just use the built-in recording tool. However, I am unable to get the cursor being rendered in the video as well.

I already tried to disable "Mouse Integration" but that's not doing it.

Any idea how I can do that?

The host is a Windows 10 installation. The guest is a Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Comment: I remember a similar problem (cursor vanished when recording a vm), which was solved by going into the VirtualBox VM settings and under 'system' picking 'usb tablet' as pointing device.

Comment: I tried all three options there.. none of them worked :/

Comment: I ended up installing [SimpleScreenRecorder](https://www.maartenbaert.be/simplescreenrecorder/) on Ubuntu and record everything directly in the VM. Using a shared folder, all the video files are stored for the host to be accessible in an easy manner. Not the solution I wanted but probably the solution I deserve.